# Internet bonding with 2 port ethernet PCI Card

Tags: ethernet, pci, bonding

If I have two separate Internet lines at home with 2 separate routers, can I achieve the same results with a 2 port ethernet PCI card, than I can with an actual binding device (like a lancer nca etc.)? I only want to bond the Internet for my pc, not the rest of the users (since only I use the network).

Comment: Yes.  (Leaving as a comment, as I feel like this "answer" is a bit incomplete/vague.)  Windows can route, using the "Routing and Remote Access" feature.  (Might only be in Windows Server operating systems, or maybe some Pro releases?)  May want to research features like network traffic prioritization, or possibly teaming/bonding features?

Answer (score 3):

No

If you connect both internet devices, you'll have two internet connections - you can leave windows to choose which way to route the traffic over them, but you won't have a 'combined' connection using both of them, instead it's still 2 separate connections.

There is various programs which will 'make the most use' of two connections however this just increases your overall bandwidth generally - it won't 'increase' your max speed by combining them or anything like that.